# Combine community detection with connected components grouping igraph R

Tags: r, igraph

I use igraph `cluster_spinglass` to detect compartments (communities) in a directed network but that only works for connected components

```
g <-   graph_from_literal( 1 -+ 4 -+ 7,2 -+ 5 -+ 9, 4+-5,
                       3 -+ 6,5 -+8, 8-+ 9, simplify = FALSE)
m<-cluster_spinglass(g)
```

Gives an error, the solution is to extract the connected component

```
dg <- components(g)
g1 <- induced_subgraph(g, which(dg$membership == which.max(dg$csize))) 
m<-cluster_spinglass(g1)
```

I get the memberships of the nodes (vertices) with

```
m$membership
```

But here I don't have all the nodes of the original network `g`, I would like to add another group with these nodes so I have all the original nodes clasified in different groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just transfer this into your original graph g.
In your example, I think that you just want the vertices in the 
other connected component to be another community, it suffices to assign all nodes in the second component to group 3.

```
V(g)$membership = 3
V(g)[V(g1)$name]$membership = m$membership
V(g)$membership
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 2
```

But in a more general example, there might be multiple components and those components might break up into multiple communities.
To cover that, you can loop through all components, compute the communities and then transfer those back to the original graph.

```
V(g)$membership = 0
for(comp in unique(dg$membership)) {
    g1 <- induced_subgraph(g, which(dg$membership == comp))
    m<-cluster_spinglass(g1)
    V(g)[V(g1)$name]$membership = m$membership + max(V(g)$membership)
}
V(g)$membership
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 2
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the network is not named so I added  `if(!is.named(g)) V(g)$name <- (1:vcount(g))`

Comment: can someone please take a look at my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64997562/r-connecting-graphs  thanks